# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized, but I did initialized it

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add FCM to my app, but when I tried to get the token, I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.***. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

The problem is that I'm already initializing the app like that, but still, the same error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, **Initialize without Firebase assistant** is a problem.

Every time I clicked 'Connect to Firebase' in my project (Kotlin, AndroidX project with Android Studio 3.3.1) and Studio says 'Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync'.

So, I tried to add the project to firebase and grab some 'google-services.json' into module folder and run application. After some build time, my application has crashed immediately because of 'Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp'.

After on some waste of time shoveling, I can resolve this issue in this way.

1. Install Android Studio 3.2.1 Stable.
2. Open your project in AS 3.2.1
3. downgrade your plugin version to 3.2.1 in build.gradle of root folder
4. Open Firebaser Assistant and click 'Connect to Firebase'
5. When process is done, back to AS 3.3.1
6. Resync gradle and build application

This solution may not your proper solution, but you can try it.